# SQL update field from same table - is self join necessary?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, self-join

I want the null fields of a column to be filled from another column in the same record. I got it to work, only I'm not sure it is stable enough.

This works:

```
UPDATE tblEmbryo 
SET tblEmbryo.cl_3c = [tblEmbryo].[cl_4c]
WHERE (((tblEmbryo.cl_3c) Is Null));
```

But don't I need a self join? Or another Where to specify that I want the field from that same record? Won't not having this cause some unexpected behaviour later? Am I missing something fundamental?

So, why not this:

```
UPDATE tblEmbryo 
INNER JOIN tblEmbryo AS tblEmbryo_1 ON tblEmbryo.ID = tblEmbryo_1.ID 
SET tblEmbryo.cl_3c = [tblEmbryo_1].[cl_4c]
WHERE (((tblEmbryo.cl_3c) Is Null));
```

Or this:

```
UPDATE tblEmbryo, tblEmbryo AS tblEmbryo_1 
SET tblEmbryo.cl_3c = [tblEmbryo_1].[cl_4c]
WHERE (((tblEmbryo.cl_3c) Is Null) AND ((tblEmbryo.ID)=[tblEmbryo_1].[ID]));
```

Forgive the clumsy syntax.

Am I making a mistake if I use the simplest first version?

Comment: Joins are normally for when you want to _combine multiple records_ to get a result. In this case you only want a single record as both source and destination, so no, you don't need a join.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Cool, thanks. I'll sleep better now. :)

Comment: Indeed, many RDBMSs *will not allow* JOINs in UPDATE statements.

Comment: When the updated value is based on data in the updated record, there is no need to join.
Joining tables comes in handy when the updated data is received from another table, or is a manipulation on data from another table.